# Component Service Duplicate Error In Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor-webassembly

```
public class MyButton
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler OnClickEvent;
    public void EventLoad() 
    {
        OnClickEvent?.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class ToolbarService
{
    public List<MyButton> MyButtons { get; set; } = new List<MyButton>();      
    public ToolbarService()
    {
        MyButtons.Add(new MyButton
        {
            Name="Save",
            Class="btn btn-primary",               
        });
        MyButtons.Add(new MyButton
        {
            Name = "Update",
            Class = "btn btn-success",
        });
        MyButtons.Add(new MyButton
        {
            Name = "Remove",
            Class = "btn btn-danger",
        });           
    }

}

public class MyBaseComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] public ToolbarService ToolbarService { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MyEventLoads();
    }

    public void MyEventLoads() 
    {
        foreach (var item in ToolbarService.MyButtons)
        {
            item.OnClickEvent += ButtonItems;
        }

    }

    private void ButtonItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (MyButton)sender;
        switch (btn.Name)
        {
            case "Save":
                Save();
                break;
            case "Update":
                Update();
                break;
            case "Remove":
                Remove();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Remove()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Remove");
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Update");
    }

    protected virtual void Save()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Save");
    }
   }
public class ToolbarMenuBase : MyBaseComponent
{

}


public class IndexBase : MyBaseComponent
{
    protected override void Save()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Save Override");
    }

}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2WxU.png)

When the Toolbar overrides the save method of the component in the Index Page, it executes the method twice as shown in the screenshot.

When the Save button is clicked, it writes both "Base Click" and "Save Override" messages to the console. Normally, I had to write "Save Override" to the console because I override the Method on the Index Page.

Comment: I'm using Blazor Web Assembly. The _host file does not exist in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the only changes I made to the code you posted

Instead of the class definition for IndexBase I create a component file (IndexBase.razor) like this:

```
@inherits  MyBaseComponent


<input type="button" value="Save" @onclick="Save" />

@code {
    // Overrides the base class Save method
    protected override void Save()
    {
        // This will print the string "Save Override"
        Console.WriteLine("Save Override");
        // Call base class's Save method (for test purposes, of course)
        // This will output the string "Base Save"
        base.Save();
    }

}
```

Usage: `<IndexBase />`

Note: Your code is fine... Add html content (buttons, etc as I did)

Answer (score -1):

You subscribe twice to your buttons clicks events : Once in the 'ToolbarMenuBase' and once in 'IndexBase'.

Comment: The methods, which are defined as virtual methods, I'm crushing the upper class?

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you mean... You have 2 instances of `MyBaseComponent` so you subscribe twice.

Comment: One of this instance is a `IndexBase` where the `Save` method override is called as you can see in your log.

Comment: Is there any way you can suggest me? How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Depends on want you want to do. I don't get why you want to subscribe to buttons events in your toolbar